# Who calls delay_tsc() on Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I used OProfile to profiling my Linux box. During the profiling processes, I've found that besides "`native_safe_halt`" function, the "[`delay_tsc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L51)" is the second most significant function consuming cpu cycles (around 10%). It seems `delay_tsc()` is a busy loop. But who calls it and what is its function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nobody calls it directly since it's a local function inside that piece of source you link to. The way to call it is by the published `__delay()` function.

When you call `__delay()`, this will use the `delay_fn` function pointer (also local to that file) to select one of several delay functions. By default, the one selected is `delay_loop()`, which uses x86 instructions to try and mark time.

However, if `use_tsc_delay()` has been called (at boot time), it switches the function pointer to `delay_tsc()`, which uses the time stamp counter (a CPU counter) to mark time.

It's called by any kernel code that wants a reasonably reliable, high-resolution delay function. You can see all the code in the kernel that references `__delay` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__delay) (quite a few places).

I think it's probably pretty safe, in terms of profiling, to ignore the time spent in that function since its *intent* is to delay. In other words, it's not useful work that's taking a long time to perform - if callers didn't want to delay, they wouldn't call it.

Some examples from that list:

- A watchdog timer uses it to pace the cores so that their output is not mixed up with each other, by delaying for some multiple of the current core ID.
- The ATI frame buffer driver appears to use it for delays between low-level accesses to the hardware. In fact, it's used quite a bit for that purpose in many device drivers.
- It's used during start-up to figure out the relationship between jiffies and the actual hardware speeds.